# Antivirus for Ubuntu Desktop and Server 11.10

Tags: server, antivirus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)
>   [What antivirus programs are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79722/what-antivirus-programs-are-available)

Friends:

What is the best antivirus for Ubuntu Server and Desktop, and where i can find this.

Many Thanks.
Fernando.

Comment: Celso: to me it is the same question and is the question related to not being educated about why you do not need one ;)

Comment: well sorry about that. was just my opinion ;)

Comment: Having an antivirus is often worse than having a virus, so the best antivirus is none at all.