# How do I update ClamTk virus scanner via the terminal?

Tags: antivirus, clamav

I've decided to use ClamTk on my Ubuntu, the problem is that it just simply wont update the antivirus engine and the GUI version from the software itself.

What is the command that I could use in the terminal for the upgrade?

(By the way, does anyone know if ClamTK is a decent antivirus software? It is listed as Nº1 on the internet.)

Is there a difference between ClamAV and ClamTk?

Comment: ClamAV is a cross-platform Antivirus software that is compatible with linux, mac, and windows. it does not have a GUI. ClamTK is a linux-specific Antivirus software. it is a GUI version of ClamAV And I don't think you need an Antivirus Software in Ubuntu.

Comment: This question may be better split up into multiple questions.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 not, its cool, the OP is just confused.

Comment: See here for details on updating signatures: [Help documentation](http://clamtk.sourceforge.net/help/general-signatures-clamtk.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ClamTK is the graphical interface for ClamAV, you cannot use ClamTk without having ClamAV installed previously.

Once installed ClamAV will run in the background as a daemon and you can use the ClamTk interface in Linux to interact with it.

The ClamAV database is automatically updated via the running `clamav-freshclam` daemon started by the `/etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam` init script, there is no actual need to update it manually.

It is controlled by the `/etc/clamav/freshclam.conf` with a default configuration of checking for a new database every 1 hour

```
# Check for new database 24 times a day
Checks 24
DatabaseMirror db.local.clamav.net
DatabaseMirror database.clamav.net
```

To force update the ClamAV virus database in the terminal you can use the command

```
sudo freshclam
```

ClamAV is definitely a good anti virus software, for a list and more information about anti virus for Ubuntu please have a look at any of the following posts

- [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)
- [What antivirus programs are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79722/what-antivirus-programs-are-available)

Comment: Bruno, it's impossible to update this software. :) None of the commands work on it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Elysium going to give it a go and let you know tonight.

Comment: @Elysium I edited the answer with some more information, you cannot update the ClamAV database using ClamTk, it is done automatically via the `freashclam` daemon or you can force the update with `sudo freshclam`.