# Error message in Avast!

Tags: antivirus

I downloaded Avast using terminal command `wget http://files.avast.com/files/linux/avast4workstation_1.3.0-2_i386.deb` and the download and installation was successful.
Then I chose `check updates(database)` from the interface. As soon as the updates were downloaded the following problem started.

```
An error occurred in avast! engine: Invalid argument
```

What should I do to correct the problem?

Answer (score 7):

This is a known problem in Avast. You need to increase the maximum amount of shared memory allowed.

- To load it without rebooting `sudo sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=128000000`
- To make it permanent, edit the file /etc/sysctl.conf (`gksudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`), and add this line to the end of the file `kernel.shmmax = 128000000`

Comment: thank you. I used the first option and I have managed to get it to work. the second option, i don't know how to carry it out. what should i do to carry it out?

Comment: There, I changed the program nano to gedit, so you can edit graphically.

Comment: This didn't work for me but using 256... worked instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use Puppy Linux Slacko and this solution worked for me.

I've a 4GB memory. So this solution, I guess will work for computers with higher memory not low ones.

Insert

```
SHMMAX=`sysctl -n kernel.shmmax`
[ $SHMMAX -lt 128000000 ] && sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=128000000
```

in /usr/lib/avast4workstation/bin/wrapper-script.sh

Then Open terminal and type

```
sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=200000000
```

Hit Enter.

And then start avast. Now Avast works!