# Where is the antivirus?

Tags: antivirus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What antivirus programs are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79722/what-antivirus-programs-are-available)

friends,

I didn´t find antivirus in this new version.
I updated into the Ubuntu and not from a separated disk.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Please specify more details. What program are you talking about. Give some links or name

Comment: Welcome Rogerio.You upgraded and not "updated",right? Did you mean,Antivirus program is missing from Software Center?

Comment: Yes. In the previuos Ubuntu version there was the antivirus called "ESCANEAR", and now, he did miss.

Comment: May it be that you are not looking for an antivirus scanner but a tool to operate your picture scanner? This would then be the package **simple-scan**. Maybe it was not translated to your locale. Just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

'sudo apt-get install nautilus-clamscan'

I'm not familiar with escanear, but clamav will work for antivirus purposes.