# Issues regarding antivirus

Tags: installation, antivirus

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I am unable to install install antivirus software. Help me to install the software.

Comment: Check this [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](http://askubuntu.com/q/10373) Please understand, ubuntu is complete different OS other than windows .. so softwares for windows will not work in ubuntu.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79722/what-antivirus-programs-are-available/80021#80021

Answer (score 1):

Don't know - I had already an Apple-Trojan in my machine ...
This Trojan was only found by avast, but not by clamTK ... it sounds weird, but I have avast installed for Linux. You can get it here :

http://avast.softpedia.com/#nx_linux

or here it is - as short description specially for Ubuntu :

http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=91145.0

More details for little trouble-shooting you find there in forum.avast.com

You will get free License-Code for 1 Year, when you mail to support@avast.com

For emergency cases you can obtain a rescue-CD from Kaspersky for free - it bases on Linux as live-CD :

http://support.kaspersky.com/4162

Rescue-CD of Kaspersky creates a directory for Kaspersky in your home-directory of your Linux-Installation, when running as Live-System, only for to store the recent search-results and for found malware in Quarantaine (to send to Kaspersky-Labs - if new - then delete them).

something forgotten - there can be rootkits too, but this is rare :

> sudo apt-get install rkhunter

and

> sudo apt-get install unhide

Think now this thread is complete.

Comment: @Shivam have added something.

Answer (score 0):

Most viruses are not compatible with Ubuntu, so usually an anti-virus is not necessary. However, there are a few reasons why you may want an antivirals:

1. to scan a Windows drive in your PC
2. to scan a Windows-based network attached server or hard drive
3. to scan Windows machines over a network
4. to protect a Windows virtual machine from within the virtual machine
5. to scan files you are going to send to other people
6. to scan e-mail you are going to forward to other people
7. some Windows viruses can run with Wine.
8. Linux virus infections are theoretically possible.

If you still want to install an anti-virus, there is a list of anti-viruses compatible with Ubuntu on the Ubuntu Wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus#Open_Source_Antivirus

<sup>Source:[Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu does not need an antivirus, as most of the time everything you will install comes from the Software Center. the software within the Software Center is considered safe and has been reviewed and used many times. 
On another note, the most popular antivirus for linux, Avast! Antivirus, was dropped by the Avast company, so if you still feel the need for an antivirus, you have nearly zero choices.

Comment: Zero choices? The following link dissagrees with you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware#Anti-virus_applications

Comment: Not the one to argue, however this is someone wanting to install an antivirus on Ubuntu. Typing in 'antivirus' on software center yields zero results. Also, three is close to zero taking into consideration how many antiviruses are available for other OSes.

Comment: maybe because you have to download them, and the only reason I can come up with having an AV is either scanning a windows drive or having a mail server.....
But we don't need many AVs, just good AVs.