# Ubuntu 14 home/personal use version of Windows Update or apt-get "Must Dos" for Security

Tags: 14.04, security

What basic security measures should be taken for Ubuntu's distro for home/personal use. No apache or web server installed.

Comment: Security is a very broad topic and as such this question is likely to be closed as too broad.

Comment: If you want a software firewall, look at ufw. That is command-line only, so you'll want gufw too for a GUI. Also, please don't call it Linux. I see this mistake from beginners all the time. Linux is just a kernel. If you're learning about what you call "Linux" you absolutely must read this official page from the GNU Foundation. I think you will find it interesting. https://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.html

Comment: Thanks for the link Fuzzy. So I should refer to the distribution package, E.G. Ubuntu (what I'm running.) I did enable the ufw as well as enabled the harddrive encryption (one of many I found.) I didn't know which encryption is the best so I just installed one of them. I'm learning more every day and it's definitely bringing the kid back in me and getting me excited to learn more which in turn is sparking my drive to learn more programming languages. +++.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of places to start would be to look at [The Big Ol' Ubuntu Security Resource](http://www.itsecurity.com/features/ubuntu-secure-install-resource/)
, which seems to be fairly current, and [BasicSecurity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity), which is perhaps a bit more dated.

There are a lot of ideas about security both on this site ad on the web in general, but your question is really broad.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Well for Windows, I'd suggest to get a router  of course for protection as well as a software firewall like Norton or McAfee and keep up-to-date on Windows Updates to keep holes in the software closed. But in Ubuntu and distro's like it, I hear you don't really need anti-virus software because no viruses (or not many) are developed for Linux and just to turn on the default firewall and that's basically it. But it seems to simple...there must be more? For web servers with apache and other software installed I understand that may need more security.

Comment: I can understand that Apache is software itself and that may need security precautions but maybe I should have just said for personal/home use is what security measures I'm wondering to take.

Comment: @tommydevs I've read the same argument about antivirus for Linux, but I don't really buy it.  I think part of this is because virus examples are rare for Linux, removing them is less well documented.  Two good answers to this can be found at http://askubuntu.com/questions/79722/what-antivirus-programs-are-available and http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed