# firewall and virus protection

Tags: firewall

I am new to ubuntu 18.04.1 lts it says that( **A built in firewall and virus protection are avaliable**) it says to go to activities left payne but there are no icons there for firewall or virus protection.

Do l need the internet set up on ubuntu for it to show. Does avaliable mean l have to start it, enable it or what?.

Can you please tell me where l can find it as it describes, It also says that yo get addded security with App Armor and gnomekeyring but where are these too as l cant find them anywhere.

Comment: Who said and where was it said please provide a link!

Comment: Techspot said it George, https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5068-ubuntu.html

Comment: describing ubuntu 18.04.1lts download, l searched it came up how where to download ubuntu and described it at techspot

Comment: It says;You can surf in safety with Ubuntu-confident that your files and data will stay protected. A built in firewall and virus protection are available.And if a potential threat appears we provide automatic updates which you can install in a single click.You get added security with AppArmor, which protects your important applications so attackers can't access your system.And thanks to Firefox and gnome-keyring,Ubuntu helps you keep your private information private.So whether it's accessing your bank account  or sharing sensitive data with friends or colleagues, you'll have peace of mind when

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu does indeed ship with a firewall by default, [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html.en) (stands for Uncomplicated FireWall ) to be specific, since [version 8.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall). There's only command-line front-end to the firewall in default installation, and you can enable that via

```
sudo ufw enable
```

There is optional GUI front-end, called GUFW. It's available in default software repositories and can be installed via Software Center or `sudo apt install gufw` in terminal.

As for virus protection I'm assuming you're talking about antivirus.  Long story short, due to differences between Windows and Linux systems you're safe from Windows specific malware and in general Linux users do not use antivirus, however such software is still available for installation. See [What antivirus programs are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/79722/295286)

Note that you don't need internet connection to enable firewall, though you do need internet connection for installing software from repositories.

Comment: so which firewall should l have UFW or the GUFW one.So l need to type in that sudo ufw enable in the terminal do l ect and it does it.l am not used to this terminal l used windows and didnt need to type in anything anywhere.The article says that a built in firewall and virus protection are available so where is this anti virus one it describes.

Comment: @user905582 They're exactly the same thing. Actual firewall is called `iptables`, and `uwf` and `gufw` are front ends. But it's complex. The `ufw` is command-line front end. The `gufw` is GUI front end. Pick which one you want to use - command line or GUI.  As for virus protection, I've already explained that in the answer. There's no app built-in, it's just that Windows viruses simply don't work on Linux (there's more details to that, but that's the simple gist of it all).

Comment: To Sergiy, is l tried to install Comodo antivirus but gave up it configured it in terminal but then said file couldn't be found when l cliked on the icon, then l tried Sophos antivirus then it only said save in temp somewhere with some stuff ball or something never heard of so l gave up it only let you save in downloads so l didn't know how to do that ball thing  in temp before you put the sudo instructi0n in,but only gave one option to save in downloads and l didn't know what that meant,

Comment: then l tried clam av it installed out of repository so l suppose thats what arcticle meant antiviris is available to have from Ubuntu programs in ubuntu 18.04.1lts.










 Backports
The Ubuntu backports repository will contain the newest clamav version that has been at least lightly tested to work with that version. These packages can be installed by enabling the backports repository on your system.
Ubuntu packages are maintained by Ubuntu MOTU Developers.

Comment: There were 2 ways to get it download from ubuntu or from terminal l did it from terminal and got the clam av and the front thing clamtk too. Then l got both back and front firewall UFW and GUFW l suppose you are allowed to have both because both are enabled.Then l scanned and got 11 posssible threats This is them being the download form ubuntu way from same site(The latest stable release is 0.101.0 
file
Modified
Size

clamav-0.101.0.tar.gz
2018-12-03 15:59:09 UTC 
20.7 MB 
So is the clamav and tk the one the article said is avaliable from ubuntu 18.04.1lt

Comment: is that the anti virus avaliable that  l asked and how do you get threats when you aren't suppose to get any there was 11 thanks.Also am l allowed to have 2 firewall going as it says in terminal l have?

Comment: Find Sophos Anti-Virus or Linux Free Edition and click Download. Follow the instructions to download the tarball to a temporary directory, for example /tmp.
2.Change to the temporary directory and untar the tarball: tar -xzvf tarball.This is what Sophos anti virus wanted me to do but it would only let me save download in downloads l don't know what this means, l wanted this one because it has email protection incase l get windows virus and infect another pc using windows.

Comment: The Comodo l think had to be saved maybe in temp so how do l do it when it only gives you the option to save then it goes straight to downloads in Ubuntu.l had to give sudo instructions to configure it, it said successful but again when l click on the icon it said file couldn't be found how is this so when the terminal message said comodo configured successfully The 11 potentil threats were all from the clamav download from ubuntu same page which was the 2nd way to get it installed.

Comment: l tried to install it that way but when l clicked on the download file again it said file not found so l did it from the terminal way.