# Emsisoft Emergency Kit does not download updates in Wine

Tags: updates, wine, internet, downloads, playonlinux

i recently installed Emsisofts Free Emergency Kit on a laptop, to make sure no Windows virusses will get anywhere. just to make sure.
I followed the same path i did with previous installments of Emergency Kit on other pcs, i installed Wine and Playonlinux to make sure.
I can run Emsisoft Emergency Kit with wine as normal, but when i click update, it says cannot download any updates. 
I checked this with firewall (ufw) off and on, no difference. btw other programs in linux run fine on that system, there is a valid internet connection. i do not know what i am doing wrong here. can anyone tell me anything of what i can do to solve this ?
(i tried installing different versions of wine also in playonlinux also the newest,and trying to run it from there, but again no positive result)
the laptop runs Xubuntu 18.04 lts , and
i also checked the server of Emsisoft is not down also, on other pcs it just updates a usual.

Comment: Hint: [AppDB on WineHQ for "Applications by Emsi Software, GMBH"](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=vendor&iId=5528&sAction=view&sTitle=View+Developer)--Their application is rated as 'garbage' by WineHQ. In other word: Unsupported.

Comment: Consider getting an [antivirus which can run in Ubuntu directly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79722/what-antivirus-programs-are-available). @clearkimura I guess running almost any Windows application in Wine is unsupported…

Comment: i have an alternative that is Clam (+ ClamTK) installed, but i want to make sure not any virus will get trough on any of my systems, so i choose Emsisofts EEK for extra additional protection, and because it is free. I guess i will have to rely on Clam than only on that pc.